# Symfony2: multiple entities, single provider?

Tags: entity-framework, symfony

I'm writing a small system where you have two kinds of users: Buyers and Sellers. When a user registers, it can be either a Buyer or a Seller. However, i'm not sure how to design this on the framework.

Should i have an `User` entity, which implements `UserInterface` and have a OneToOne relationship of that entity with `Buyer` or `Seller`? Or should `Buyer` and `Seller` implement `UserInterface`, therefore having multiple providers?

ps.: Buyer and Seller have different columns and different relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I would not split this up into 2 entities. Just have one user entity and use roles to make the difference between a seller and a buyer. In the end, the only difference is their privileges, which is all handled by the Security system.

Comment: I agree, you'll want to make sure that all users are stored in the same table. Otherwise, what if a `Buyer` is also a `Seller`? Would he need two accounts? And what if a buyer and seller create an account using the same username? Storing them all in one table, you can be sure that every username is unique, and you can give one user both buyer and seller permissions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have 2 entities for this.

Just use the `User` entity and assume by default that all users are buyers (that's the most common case in marketplaces) but only a handful of the users are sellers, so I would just add a property to your Entity this way:

```
/**
 *@ORM\Column(name="isSeller", type="boolean", options={"default"=0})
 **/
 private $isSeller;

 public function setIsSeller($isSeller) {
     $this->isSeller = $isSeller;
     return $this;
  }

 public function getIsSeller() {
     return $this->isSeller;
 }
```

And just set the the property to `true` whenever a User chooses to be a seller as well.

Comment: Also: Buyer and Seller have different columns and different relationships.

Comment: If buyers and sellers have different relationship, then it makes sense to have a separate entity for sellers-only attributes. However, also think about the user experience of your marketplace. Most marketplaces out there have only one login whether you are a seller or a buyer because it is easier for end users to use the marketplace. Have a seller's entity, with a UserID One-To-One relationship  and in that entity you put seller's specifics and join on UserID where IsSeller = true.

Comment: Would it be expensive? depending on what DBMS you're using. Joins is what RDBMS do best, so as long as UserID and other important columns are properly indexed I don't see this solutions any less efficient than what you were already considering. 

Efficiency is important, but also think about the possible queries you will need to write whenever someone needs data from your database.